# Interior and closure of $A := \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\ |\ \ x^2+y^2>1\}$

Tags: general-topology

I have the set

$$A := \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\  |\ \  x^2+y^2>1\}$$

Now I would like to find the interior, the closure, the boundary and isolated points. I am not quite sure where to start. I am pretty sure the set of all inner points are all $(x,y)$ for which $x^2+y^2>1$. I have the definitions infront of me but I have not done a formal proof of something like this before, so I am a little bit confused of what I actually have to do.

Any help would be very kindly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $A=\{\bar x\in\Bbb R^2: \|\bar x\|>1\}$.

For each $\bar x\in A$ you need to find a ball that is entirely outside of $A$. Make a drawing.

The radius $\epsilon$ of this ball should be no greater than $\|\bar x\|-1$.

Now you must prove what is apparent in your drawing. Namely, that no point of the ball is in $A$. So take $\bar y\in B(\bar x,\epsilon)$. Checking that $\bar y\notin A$ is checking that $\|\bar y\|>1$.

$$\|\bar y\|=\|\bar x+\bar y-\bar x\|\ge\|\bar x\|-\|\bar y-\bar x\|>1+\epsilon-\epsilon$$

Comment: I am not quite sure whether I understood something wrongly here or not,but why do I need to find a ball that is outside of $A$ ? With a radius of no greater than $||x||-1$ I would have a ball which is always completely inside of $A$, right?

Answer (score 0):

The complement of $A$ is $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\  |\ \  x^2+y^2 \le 1\}$. What can you say about $A$?

The boundary of $A$ is the boundary of $A^c$, and $cl(A^c)$ is the interior of $A^c$ union the boundary of $A^c$, so the boundary of $A$ is...

$cl(A)$ is $A$ union the boundary of $A$, so...